# rayleigh distribution curve on histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have an array of velocity data in directions V_x and V_y. I've plotted a histogram for the velocity norm using the code below,

```
plt.hist(V_norm_hist, bins=60, density=True, rwidth=0.95)
```

which gives the following figure:
[image: Histograph for velocity norm]

Now I also want to add a Rayleigh Distribution curve on top of this, but I can't get it to work. I've been trying different combinations using scipy.stats.rayleigh but the [scipy homepage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html) isn't really intuative so I can't get it to function properly... 
What exactly does the lines

```
mean, var, skew, kurt = rayleigh.stats(moments='mvsk')
```

and

```
x = np.linspace(rayleigh.ppf(0.01),rayleigh.ppf(0.99), 100)
ax.plot(x, rayleigh.pdf(x),'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='rayleigh pdf')
```

do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to first follow the link to [`rv_continuous`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous), from which [`rayleigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html) is subclassed. And from there to the [`ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf) to find out that `ppf` is the 'Percent point function'. `x0 = ppf(0.01)` tells at which spot everything less than `x0` has [accumulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) 1% of its total 'weight' and similarly `x1 = ppf(0.99)` is where 99% of the 'weight' is accumulated. [`np.linspace(x0, x1, 100)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) divides the space from x0 to x1 in 100 short intervals. As a continuous distribution can be infinite, these x0 and x1 limits are needed to only show the interesting interval.

[`rayleigh.pdf(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.pdf.html) gives the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) at x. So, an indication of how probable each x is.

[`rayleigh.stats(moments='mvsk')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.stats.html) where moments is *composed of letters [‘mvsk’] defines which moments to compute: ‘m’ = [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean), ‘v’ = [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), ‘s’ = [(Fisher’s) skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness), ‘k’ = [(Fisher’s) kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis).*

To plot both the histogram and the distribution on the same plot, we need to know the parameters of Raleigh that correspond to your sample (`loc` and `scale`). Furthermore, both the pdf and the histogram would need the same `x` and same `y`. For the `x` we can take the limits of the histogram bins. For the `y`, we can scale up the pdf, knowing that the total area of the pdf is supposed to be 1. And the histogram bins are proportional to the number of entries.

If you do know the `loc` is `0` but don't know the `scale`, [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Properties) gives a formula that connects the `scale` to the mean of your samples:

```
estimated_rayleigh_scale = samples.mean() / np.sqrt(np.pi / 2)
```

Supposing a `loc` of `0` and a `scale` of `0.08` the code would look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rayleigh

N = 1000
# V = np.random.uniform(0, 0.1, 2*N).reshape((N,2))
# V_norm = (np.linalg.norm(V, axis=1))
scale = 0.08
V_norm_hist = scale * np.sqrt( -2* np.log (np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

num_bins = 60
_binvalues, bins, _patches = plt.hist(V_norm_hist, bins=num_bins, density=False, rwidth=1, ec='white', label='Histogram')
x = np.linspace(bins[0], bins[-1], 100)
binwidth = (bins[-1] - bins[0]) / num_bins

scale = V_norm_hist.mean() / np.sqrt(np.pi / 2)

plt.plot(x, rayleigh(loc=0, scale=scale).pdf(x)*len(V_norm_hist)*binwidth, lw=5, alpha=0.6, label=f'Rayleigh pdf (s={scale:.3f})')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]